# using geofencing in android or ios

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, geofencing

I want to know that is it possible to use geofencing feature without any app installed? is there some cloud or something which you can register your geofencing area so anyone with the location on can see your notifications??

Comment: Without app installed how user will notified ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Android, but for iOS you can use [Apple Wallet Passes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW1). You can attach up to 10 locations (geo points) to your passes, and when the device that installed the pass is near one of those locations, the pass will appear on the lock screen.

> Relevance Information Displays Passes on the Lock Screen
>
> Passes let your users take some action in the real world, so accessing them needs to be easy and fast. Wallet makes relevant passes immediately accessible by integrating them with the lock screen. To take advantage of this feature, add >information about where and when your pass is relevant. A pass’s relevancy can be based either on the time or the place where the user can actually utilize it. For example, a gym membership is relevant at the gym, while a boarding pass is relevant at the time the flight begins boarding.
>
> Inside the pass, you provide a point in time and points in space. Wallet then determines whether the pass should appear on the lock screen based on these settings. It calculates when the user is close enough to the specified time and locations based on the pass’s style. Don’t try to manipulate the pass’s presence on the lock screen by providing inaccurate relevance information.

Of course, integrating with Apple Wallet requires your own web server, and is not a simple task. However, It doesn't require any app installed, which is what you asked about.